# Slider not working in home component in Angular4 Web-App

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have created web app using angular4. All pages working properly with routing. The default page is a home page. 
Slider working perfect in home page When the app is loaded after that slider not working when I go to another page and then coming into a home page. 
I have loads all external css and js into index.html page. 
In home component, load just content with slider and some scripts for slider load into the one-night method. Home page works properly when page refresh or load

First time slider working in home page, but slider not working in the home page when change page using routing. Anyone know what is the issue here?

home.component.ts

```
import { CommonScriptComponent } from './../common-script/common-
 script.component';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
 selector: 'home',
 templateUrl: './home.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
 })
 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private commonScriptComponent:CommonScriptComponent) { }

 ngOnInit() {
 this.commonScriptComponent.onLoad();

 }






}
```

Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Web, Mobile App, CRM, vTiger & ODOO Development Company India | Veepal</title>
<meta name="description" content="Veepal IT Services is Website, Mobile Application for iPhone & Android, Graphics Design, ERP, CRM, vTiger & ODOO Development Company in India.">
<meta name="keywords" content="wordpress development company india, hire wordpress developer india, Hire Codeigniter developer, Codeigniter framework development, Salesforce CRM development, odoo development, odoo customization & Migration, vTiger CRM Development, affordable seo services india, best digital marketing company india, top digital marketing agency india, guaranteed seo services india, cheap seo packages india, offshore web development company, responsive website development india, Custom php development company India, core php development company India, hire php developer india, custom cms development company, offshore cms development company, hire cms developer, hire android app developer, android app development company India, hire ios app developer, ios application development company, iphone application development company, Microsoft Dynamics CRM? Development, Sage CRM module Development, Sugar CRM module Development, Custom coldfusion development india, Hire Magento Developer India, Magento development company india, ecommerce website development india, magento ecommerce development, Hire Laravel Developers, Custom Laravel development india, Hire .net Developers, Custom .net development india, Hire DotNetNuke Developers, Custom DotNetNuke development india, Hire Python Developers, Custom Python development india, Hire MEAN Stack Developer, Mean stack development, Hire Full Stack Developer, full stack development, hire java developer India, custom java development india">
<meta property="twitter:url" content="http://www.veepal.com/">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.veepal.com/">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.veepal.com/">
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOYDIR,NOODP">
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="KpLSxTAPqnxGuygv1GajjqhDjAgL6skG0f47PE7n3Oo">
<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="5D74C2D02269A257714752651F59C85A">
<meta name="alexaVerifyID" content="0zTAiY6o4WrSt4zIb8iTaapixEE">
<meta name="p:domain_verify" content="a4b905b4d212fdffdbe48e61ff04ba06">
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/+Veepal/posts">
<link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/102356317964360660690">
<meta property="og:title" content="Web Design &amp; Mobile Development India - Veepal IT services">
<meta property="og:description" content="Veepal IT services creates a unique blend of IT technology solutions by providing web design and development, mobile development and search engine optimisation.">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Veepal IT Services">
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/Software.Development.India">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="146507655407127">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@veepal">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@veepal">
<meta property="twitter:title" content="Web Design &amp; Mobile Development India | Veepal.com">
<meta property="twitter:description" content="Veepal IT services creates a unique blend of IT technology solutions by providing web design and development, mobile development and search engine optimisation.">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<base href="/">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">



<!-- Start Added header for link all css -->

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,100,300,500,700%7CLato:400,300,700,900&subset=latin,latin-ext'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- Plugins CSS files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/assets.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/shortcodes.css">
<!-- REVOLUTION SLIDER STYLES -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/revolution/fonts/pe-icon-7-stroke/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/revolution/css/settings.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/revolution/css/navigation.css" type="text/css">
<link id="theme_css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/light.css">
<link id="skin_css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/skins/default.css">
<!-- Font icon css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konpa/devicon/df6431e323547add1b4cf45992913f15286456d3/devicon.min.css">
<link href='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/devicons/1.8.0/css/devicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
    .icon_shape,
    .videoContainer {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden
    }

    .icon_shape {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 39px;
        margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 40px
    }

    .services {
        background-color: #F8F8F8
    }

    .case-studies a.link.main-bg {
        left: 100px!important
    }

    .portfolio-item .icon-links {
        top: 0!important
    }

    .tp-video-play-button {
        display: none!important
    }

    .videoContainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-attachment: scroll
    }

    .videoContainer .overlay {
        background-image: url(assets/images/video-banner.png);
        background-position: center center;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 1.0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 2
    }

    .slid-title {
        font-size: 30px!important;
        margin: 0 auto
    }

    .rev_slider .caption1,
    .rev_slider .tp-caption1 {
        margin-top: 45px!important
    }
</style>
 <!-- End Added header for link all css -->

 </head>

  <body>
<!-- <app-root></app-root> -->
<!-- Start Body -->
<div class="page-loader"></div>
<div class="pageWrapper">
    <!-- <?php include 'header_menu_semi_transperent.php'; ?> -->


    <!-- Start Header Menu -->
    <link id="font_css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/lang_font/lang-font.css">

    <!--<div class="head-border"></div>-->

    <!-- Header start -->


    <app-root>

    </app-root>



    <div class="modal fade modal-register t-left" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-register">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">


                <!-- Begin # Login Form -->
                <!-- <?php include 'contact-form.php'; ?> -->
                <!-- Strat Contact Form -->
                <form class="ajax-form1 popup" name="contact" action="assets/php/sendemail.php" id="inquiry-form" method="post">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>

                        <h2 class="t-center">Inquire Now
                            <small>
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Safe & Confidential</small>
                        </h2>
                        <hr class="colorgraph">
                        <div class="red" style="text-align: center;"></div>
                        <div class="green" style="color: green;text-align: center;"></div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="first-name" id="first_name" class="form-control ifname" placeholder="First Name">
                                    <lable class="iifname red_cl"></lable>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="last-name" id="last_name" class="form-control ilname" placeholder="Last Name">
                                    <lable class="iilname red_cl"></lable>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="contact-email" id="email" class="form-control iemail" placeholder="Email Address">
                                    <lable class="iiemail red_cl"></lable>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control iphone" placeholder="Phone">
                                    <lable class="iiphone red_cl"></lable>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select id="contact-service" name="country" class="form-control icontry">
                                        <option selected="selected">Country</option>
                                        <option>Africa</option>
                                        <option>Argentina</option>
                                        <option>Australia</option>
                                        <option>Austria</option>
                                        <option>Bahamas</option>
                                        <option>Bahrain</option>
                                        <option>Belarus</option>
                                        <option>Belgium</option>
                                        <option>Bolivia</option>
                                        <option>Brazil</option>
                                        <option>Beijing</option>
                                        <option>Canada</option>
                                        <option>China</option>
                                        <option>Colombia</option>
                                        <option>Costa Rica</option>
                                        <option>Croatia (Hrvatska)</option>
                                        <option>Czech Republic</option>
                                        <option>Denmark</option>
                                        <option>Dominican Republic</option>
                                        <option>Egypt</option>
                                        <option>Estonia</option>
                                        <option>Finland</option>
                                        <option>France</option>
                                        <option>Germany</option>
                                        <option>Ghana</option>
                                        <option>Greece</option>
                                        <option>Hong Kong</option>
                                        <option>Hungary</option>
                                        <option>India</option>
                                        <option>Indonesia</option>
                                        <option>Iran</option>
                                        <option>Ireland</option>
                                        <option>Italy</option>
                                        <option>Japan</option>
                                        <option>Kenya</option>
                                        <option>Korea</option>
                                        <option>Kuwait</option>
                                        <option>Malawi</option>
                                        <option>Malaysia</option>
                                        <option>Mexico</option>
                                        <option>Namibia</option>
                                        <option>Netherlands</option>
                                        <option>New Zealand</option>
                                        <option>Nicaragua</option>
                                        <option>Nigeria</option>
                                        <option>Norway</option>
                                        <option>Oman</option>
                                        <option>Pakistan</option>
                                        <option>Panama</option>
                                        <option>Peru</option>
                                        <option>Philippines</option>
                                        <option>Poland</option>
                                        <option>Portugal</option>
                                        <option>Qatar</option>
                                        <option>Romania</option>
                                        <option>Russian Federation</option>
                                        <option>Saudi Arabia</option>
                                        <option>Serbia</option>
                                        <option>Singapore</option>
                                        <option>South Africa</option>
                                        <option>Spain</option>
                                        <option>Sri Lanka</option>
                                        <option>Sudan</option>
                                        <option>Swaziland</option>
                                        <option>Sweden</option>
                                        <option>Switzerland</option>
                                        <option>Thailand</option>
                                        <option>United Arab Emirates</option>
                                        <option>United Kingdom</option>
                                        <option>United States of America</option>
                                        <option>Others</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <lable class="iicontry red_cl"></lable>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input style="margin-top: 0px;" type="text" name="skype-whatsapp" id="skype" class="form-control iskype" placeholder="Skype ID/ Whatsapp No.">
                                    <lable class="iiskype red_cl"></lable>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea id="contact-message" name="contact-message" rows="6" cols="30" class="form-control imessage" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            <lable class="iimessage red_cl"></lable>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div id="RecaptchaField2"></div>
                            <label class="igg-recaptcha-response msg-error red_cl"></label>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="colorgraph">
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div>
                                <input id="inq_button" type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="7">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- End Contact Form -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log(document.cookie); var visit = getCookie("cookie"); if (null == visit) { setTimeout(function () { $("#myModal").modal("show") }, 90000), show_contact_captcha(); var expire = new Date, m = 20; expire = new Date(expire.getTime() + 60 * m * 1e3), document.cookie = "cookie=here; expires=" + expire }
        });


        function del_cookie(e) { document.cookie = e + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;" }

        function getCookie(e) { var n = document.cookie, i = n.indexOf(" " + e + "="); if (-1 == i && (i = n.indexOf(e + "=")), -1 == i) n = null; else { i = n.indexOf("=", i) + 1; var f = n.indexOf(";", i); -1 == f && (f = n.length), n = unescape(n.substring(i, f)) } return n }
    </script>

    <!-- End Header Menu -->


    <!-- End Header Menu -->

    <!-- <?php include 'footer_transperent.php'; ?> -->
    <!-- Start footer  -->


    <!-- Footer end -->
    <!-- Back to top Link -->
    <a id="to-top" href="#">
        <span class="fa fa fa-angle-up"></span>
    </a>
    <!-- Load JS plugins -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/assets.js"></script>
    <!-- SLIDER REVOLUTION  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
    <!-- SLIDER REVOLUTION 5.0 EXTENSIONS           (Load Extensions only on Local File Systems !  +            The following part can be removed on Server for On Demand Loading) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js"></script>
    <!-- END SLIDER REVOLUTION 5.0 EXTENSIONS -->
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
        var tpj = jQuery, revapi4; tpj(window).load(function () { void 0 == tpj("#rev_slider_4_1").revolution ? revslider_showDoubleJqueryError("#rev_slider_4_1") : revapi4 = tpj("#rev_slider_4_1").show().revolution({ sliderType: "standard", jsFileLocation: "assets/revolution/js/", sliderLayout: "fullscreen", dottedOverlay: "none", delay: 9e3, navigation: { keyboardNavigation: "on", keyboard_direction: "horizontal", mouseScrollNavigation: "off", onHoverStop: "off", touch: { touchenabled: "on", swipe_threshold: 75, swipe_min_touches: 1, swipe_direction: "horizontal", drag_block_vertical: !1 }, arrows: { style: "gyges", enable: !0, hide_onmobile: !1, hide_onleave: !1, tmp: "", left: { h_align: "left", v_align: "center", h_offset: 10, v_offset: 0 }, right: { h_align: "right", v_align: "center", h_offset: 10, v_offset: 0 } }, bullets: { enable: !1, hide_onmobile: !1, style: "gyges", hide_onleave: !1, direction: "horizontal", h_align: "center", v_align: "top", h_offset: 0, v_offset: 20, space: 5, tmp: "" } }, parallax: { type: "mouse", origo: "slidercenter", speed: 2e3, levels: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 16, 10, 50] }, responsiveLevels: [1240, 1024, 778, 480], gridwidth: [1240, 1024, 778, 480], gridheight: [868, 768, 960, 720], lazyType: "none", shadow: 0, spinner: "off", stopLoop: "on", stopAfterLoops: 0, stopAtSlide: 0, shuffle: "off", autoHeight: "off", fullScreenAlignForce: "off", fullScreenOffsetContainer: "", fullScreenOffset: "", disableProgressBar: "on", hideThumbsOnMobile: "off", hideSliderAtLimit: 0, hideCaptionAtLimit: 0, hideAllCaptionAtLilmit: 0, debugMode: !1, fallbacks: { simplifyAll: "off", nextSlideOnWindowFocus: "off", disableFocusListener: !1 } }) }); 
    </script> -->
    <!-- general script file -->
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script.js"></script> -->


    <script>

         //$("#inq_button").click(function (e) { var i = $(".ifname").val(), r = $(".ilname").val(), s = $(".iemail").val(), a = $(".iphone").val(), l = $(".iskype").val(), m = $(".icontry option:selected").val(), t = $("textarea.imessage").val(), n = !0; if ("" == i) $(".iifname").html("This field is required"), $(".ifname").addClass("error"), n = !1; else { var o = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/; o.test(i) ? ($(".iifname").html(""), $(".ifname").removeClass("error")) : ($(".iifname").html("Please Enter Only Alphabate"), $(".ifname").addClass("error"), n = !1) } if ("" == r) $(".iilname").html("This field is required"), $(".ilname").addClass("error"), n = !1; else { var o = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/; o.test(r) ? ($(".iilname").html(""), $(".ilname").removeClass("error")) : ($(".iilname").html("Please Enter Only Alphabate"), $(".ilname").addClass("error"), n = !1) } if ("" == s ? ($(".iiemail").html("This field is required"), $(".iemail").addClass("error"), n = !1) : isEmaili(s) ? ($(".iiemail").html(""), $(".iemail").removeClass("error")) : ($(".iiemail").html("Please enter valid email"), $(".iemail").addClass("error"), n = !1), "" == a) $(".iiphone").html("This field is required"), $(".iphone").addClass("error"), n = !1; else { var o = /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]*$/im; a.length < 6 ? ($(".iiphone").html("Please enter minimum 6 Digits"), $(".iphone").addClass("error"), n = !1) : o.test(a) ? ($(".iiphone").html(""), $(".iphone").removeClass("error")) : ($(".iiphone").html("Please enter only numbers"), $(".iphone").addClass("error"), n = !1) } "" == l ? ($(".iiskype").html("This field is required"), $(".iskype").addClass("error"), n = !1) : ($(".iiskype").html(""), $(".iskype").removeClass("error")), "Country" == m ? ($(".iicontry").html("This field is required"), $(".icontry").addClass("error"), n = !1) : ($(".iicontry").html(""), $(".icontry").removeClass("error")), "" == t ? ($(".iimessage").html("This field is required"), $(".imessage").addClass("error"), n = !1) : t.length < 20 ? ($(".iimessage").html("Please enter minimum 20 character"), $(".imessage").addClass("error"), n = !1) : ($(".iimessage").html(""), $(".imessage").removeClass("error")), n && $("#inquiry-form").submit() });

        function isEmaili(a) { var i = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/; return i.test(a) }


    </script>

    <script>
         var CaptchaCallback = function () { $("#RecaptchaField1").length && grecaptcha.render("RecaptchaField1", { sitekey: "6Lc6pDUUAAAAABR_gK7ukk-wlsnOKgB2O4C4jF02" }), $("#RecaptchaField2").length && grecaptcha.render("RecaptchaField2", { sitekey: "6Lc6pDUUAAAAABR_gK7ukk-wlsnOKgB2O4C4jF02" }) };
         var j = 1;
         $(".inq-button").click(function () { $(".red").html(""), $(".green").html(""), $("#inquiry-form")[0].reset(), setTimeout(function () { var e = window.location.pathname, t = "contact-us"; if (-1 !== e.indexOf(t) && hide_contact_captcha(), j) { $("#RecaptchaField2").empty(), removejscssfile("api.js", "js"); var a = document.createElement("script"); a.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit", a.type = "text/javascript", document.body.parentNode.appendChild(a) } else { $("#RecaptchaField2").empty(), removejscssfile("api.js", "js"); var a = document.createElement("script"); a.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit", a.type = "text/javascript", document.body.parentNode.appendChild(a) } j = 0 }, 100) });
         $(".close").click(function () { show_contact_captcha() });

        function hide_contact_captcha() { $("#RecaptchaField1").empty(), removejscssfile("api.js", "js") }

        function show_contact_captcha() { $("#RecaptchaField1").empty(), removejscssfile("api.js", "js"); var e = document.createElement("script"); e.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit", e.type = "text/javascript", document.body.parentNode.appendChild(e) }

        function removejscssfile(e, t) { for (var n = "js" == t ? "script" : "css" == t ? "link" : "none", s = "js" == t ? "src" : "css" == t ? "href" : "none", r = document.getElementsByTagName(n), i = r.length; i >= 0; i--)r[i] && null != r[i].getAttribute(s) && -1 != r[i].getAttribute(s).indexOf(e) && r[i].parentNode.removeChild(r[i]) }
    </script>
    <!------ Start custom code of clients image slider ------>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.4-packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () { var e = $("#carousel"), i = $(window); e.carouFredSel({ align: !1, items: 10, scroll: { items: 1, duration: 2e3, timeoutDuration: 0, easing: "linear", pauseOnHover: "immediate" } }), i.bind("resize.example", function () { var r = i.width(); 990 > r && (r = 990), e.width(3 * r), e.parent().width(r) }).trigger("resize.example") });
    </script>
    <!------ End custom code of clients image slider ------>



    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.$zopim || (function (d, s) {
            var z = $zopim = function (c) { z._.push(c) }, $ = z.s =

                d.createElement(s), e = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; z.set = function (o) {
                    z.set.

                        _.push(o)
                }; z._ = []; z.set._ = []; $.async = !0; $.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8');

            $.src = '//v2.zopim.com/?2PHjsaWgIJeGDbwArhiFqLeFmURWPxId'; z.t = +new Date; $.

                type = 'text/javascript'; e.parentNode.insertBefore($, e)
        })(document, 'script');

    </script>


    <!-- End footer -->
</div>
<!-- End Body -->
```

Comment: Can you add some relevant code to your OP ? the `index.html` and your components would be useful for instance.

Comment: @Safiyya Just added index.html and home.component.ts file

Answer (score 1):

Rev slider doesn't like to get removed of DOM and added again, you should run .revkill() before removing it from DOM and .revolution(options) after adding it again.

So my simple working solution is here(Don't forget to include jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js and jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js at the end of body tag in index.html):

```js
import {
  Component,
  AfterViewInit,
  ElementRef,
  OnDestroy,
  Inject,
  PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.scss']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  slider: any;

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) { }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // RS's kill switch
    this.slider.revkill();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) { // due to server side rendering check if browser
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.slider = (<any>window).$(this.element.nativeElement)
          .find('.rev_slider')
          .revolution(this.getSliderOptions());
      }, 10);
    }
  }

  getSliderOptions(): any {
    return {
      'delay': 9000,
      'gridwidth': [1140,960,720,540],
      'gridheight': [600,600,600,600],
      'disableProgressBar': 'on',
      'responsiveLevels': [4096,1200,992,576],
      'parallax': {
        'type': 'mouse',
        'origo': 'slidecenter',
        'speed': 3000,
        'levels': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12,16,10,50],
        'disable_onmobile': 'on'
      },
      'navigation' : {
        'arrows': {
          'enable': true,
          'hide_under': 767,
          'style': 'slider-arrows-style-1 slider-arrows-dark'
        },
        'bullets': {
          'enable': true,
          'hide_under': 767,
          'style': 'bullets-style-1',
          'hide_onleave': false,
          'h_align': 'right',
          'v_align': 'bottom',
          'space': 7,
          'v_offset': 75,
          'h_offset': 35
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Why no one upvoted your answer ever I don't know. It helped me 3 years later!